# Parsing symbol separated file with variable field file format, variable fields in format key=value

Tags: awk

I have a file with records of the following format:

```
foo10|bar11|baz15|key1.1=10|key23.1=12.2|key56.2=21|key876.2=242
foo11|bar21|baz34|key56.2=25.45|key1.1=11|key23.1=11.2|key56.2=21|key876.2=242
foo13|bar13|baz16|key591=123|key1.1=11|key23.1=12.2|key876.2=242
foo23|bar34|baz16|key591=123|key23.1=1232.2|key56.2=532
```

I would like to extract first and second fields, and locate key23.1 and key56.2.
Keys are variable in length, can be in any order and can be present or not.

With that I would get something like:

```
foo10,bar11,12.2,21
foo11,bar21,11,25.45
foo13,bar13,11,
foo23,bar34,,532
```

As this is somehow two levels (like we have a | separated record and then some records have `keyX.Y=`, is awk the right tool for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS=, '
    { 
        key23 = key56 = ""
        for (i = 3; i <= NF; ++i)
            if ($i ~ /^key23\.1=/)
                key23 = substr($i, 9)
            else if ($i ~ /^key56\.2=/)
                key56 = substr($i, 9)
        print $1, $2, key23, key56
    }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `awk` can be the right tool for this task.

With GNU `awk` setting FS multicharacter, here `FS="\\\||="` we get the desired output:

```
awk -v FS="\\\||=" '
    NR==1{print $1, $2, $7, $9}
    NR==2{print $1, $2, $7, $5}
    NR==3{print $1, $2, $7}
    NR==4{print $1, $2, $9}' OFS="," file
foo10,bar11,12.2,21
foo11,bar21,11,25.45
foo13,bar13,11
foo23,bar34,532
```